# 404 Error Contact Form 7 on WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, http-status-code-404, contact-form, contact-form-7

I just created a new website. Everything seems to work perfectly except the contact form. Indeed, the contact form is not working, and affects loading after one try. 
The chrome console gave me this information:

```html
jquery-1.12.4.js:2 GET https://nameofthewebsite.fr/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/109/refill 404 ()
```

How to solve this issue?

Best regards

Comment: You might be better off asking this on wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hi. Any progress with this issue? I got the same and have zero ideas how to solve this.

Comment: I downgrade to an old contact form 7 version. You have to use the main link then, proceed as below. 

https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/contact-form-7.[VERSION].zip             Ex: For the 7 4.6.1 https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/contact-form-7.4.6.1zip Releases history is available through this link: https://contactform7.com/category/releases/ Best

Answer (score 0):

If you use a security plugin check if /wp-json/ is rewrited or blocked. In some cases change default path of /wp-json/ causes Contact Form 7 stop working

Answer (score 0):

Contact Form 7 in the 5.4 version introduces a new way of validating nonce and a few third-party plugins come in conflict with this. WooCommerce, Fastest cache, WP Rocket and a few others are reported to cause this problem. If you avoid caching pages for more than a few hours and if you update Contact Form 7 to 5.4.1 or preferrably even higher, you should be just fine.